Is is possible that a point x on surface S itself is the only closest point to x in $R^n$?
Consider a $m$-d smooth surface $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($m<n$). For any point $x\in S$, we define the neighbor region of $x$ is $N(x)=\{p| dist(p,S)=dist(p,x), p\in \mathbb{R}^n \}$, where $dist(p,S)=\min_{s\in S} dist(p,s)$ and dist denotes Euclidean distance. Is it possible that there exists one point $x\in S$ such that $N(x)=\{x\}$?
I thought such a point may not exist because it may make $S$ not smooth. But I do not know how to prove it.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Just a rough sketch but I think this is about convexity not smoothness of the surface.
First, if for a given point $x\in S$ there exists a hyperplane P through $x$ so that the surface intersects P only in $x$ (in other words, the surface is convex at $x$), then any point on the normal of the hyperplane pointing away from the surface is part of the neighbor region.
Note that if your surface is compact than it necessarily has convex points (if it is compact then it is contained in sufficiently large balls around a point, the infimum of the balls will intersect the surface in a convex point of the surface).
It shouldn't be too hard to construct an example of a surface that is concave at some point $x$ and for any point $p \neq x$ you have $d(p,S) < d(p,x)$.
